# CoreData persisten store async save

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I need to save changes from my temp context to disk without blocking the Main UI thread.
I am trying to do this like mentioned at the bottom of the article [multi-context-coredata](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/)

Do the following:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *editContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
editContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = [NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext].persistentStoreCoordinator;

[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext].parentContext = editContext;//defaultContext is my main CoreData context
```

But app crashes on on the string:

```
[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext].parentContext = editContext
```

with the following:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Context already has a coordinator;  cannot replace.'
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to insert the edit context as a parent? Probably the persistent store context (if you have one, which you should) should be the parent for the edit context and the 'default' context...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty descriptive. You're trying to assign a parent context to a context that already has a persistent store coordinator. You can't do both. A managed object context may have **either** a persistent store coordinator **or** a parent context **but not both**. With nested contexts, only the root context has a persistent store coordinator of its own. Its child contexts (and their child contexts, etc) have parent contexts instead.

If you want to create a parent context, don't assign a value for the persistent store coordinator.

If you want to assign a value for the persistent store coordinator, don't set its parent context.